# Debugging Tab command in emacs, js2-mode

Tags: indentation

Tab press in js2-mode goes to

```
indent-for-tab-command
```

in indent.el. 
This command takes a prefix argument as `arg`. Since no prefix arguments are set by `C-u`, what gets passed here?
And internally, `indent-for-tab-command` calls `insert-tab`, this calculates the variable `count` as,

```
(prefix-numeric-value arg)
```

and then does,

```
(insert-char ?\t count)
```

So, where is the js2-mode group variable, `js2-indent-level` taken into consideration for calculating the number of space chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code for `indent-for-tab-command`, you see this `interactive` spec: `(interactive "P")`. If you check the Elisp manual for `interactive` (e.g. `C-h i`, choose Elisp manual, `i interactive`) you will find the `"P"` means the raw prefix argument.

So that is what is passed to the function body: the raw prefix argument, which is the value of variable `current-prefix-arg`. See the Elisp manual for that, as well.

The manual tells you that if the user provides no prefix arg then `current-prefix-arg` is `nil`. So that is what is passed to the function body if no prefix arg is provided by the user.

You also ask about function `prefix-numeric-value`.  That too you will find explained clearly in the Elisp manual. It tells you, among other things, that `(prefix-numeric-value nil)` returns `1`.

And since `count` here is the numeric value of the prefix arg, `(insert-char ?\t count)` is just `(insert-char ?\t 1)`.

*So the* ***real*** *answer to your question is* ***how to ask Emacs about Elisp.*** The answer is `C-h i`, then choose the Elisp manual, then use `i` to look things up in the index (with completion). You can also search through the entire manual incrementally using `C-s`.

Comment: yes, that is more like a warning for me.. messed up in understanding the edge cases.. this function is supposed to use js2-indent-level to calculate the number of spaces in the place of tab command, since the buffer's major mode is js2-mode. that piece of code is still missing~~~~